# Is "that" pointing "lives" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 1. There are some people who are trying to make their boring lives interesting by criticizing others **that** they have due to wasting most of their time **criticizing others**.

Is "that" indicating the "lives" in this first sentence?
((And can I replace "criticizing others" with "doing so"?))

Or, I have to write like this

> 2. There are some people trying to make their boring lives interesting, **what boring lives** they have **because** they have wasted most of their time criticizing others.

Or,

> 3. There are some people trying to make their boring lives interesting, **what boring lives** they have **due to** wasting most of their time criticizing others.

Or,

> 4. There are some people trying to make their boring lives interesting, **boring lives** they have **because** they have wasted most of their time criticizing others.

If I replace "criticizing others" with "doing so", would my sentences still be correct?

Can you tell me any other word that I can use instead of "interesting" in my sentences?

Comment: None of your attempts work. Just to be quite clear, I assume you're ***not*** claiming the *reason* these "critics" have boring lives is *because* they criticise others. That doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but if it ***is*** what you mean you'd probably need quite a few more words to make it clear. Otherwise, just replace the curious repetitions in your first attempt: *There are some people who **waste their time** trying to make their boring lives interesting by criticizing others.* (They fact that they're "wasting" their time implies they're unsuccessful; their lives are *still* boring.)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. So can't I write like this "There are some people who waste their time to make their boring lives interesting by criticizing others that(boring lives) they have due to waste most of their time criticizing others"

Comment: "There are some people who waste their time to make their boring lives interesting by criticizing others and the reason they have boring lives is that they waste their time criticizing others." Is this version correct?

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly okay (except you missed out a word: *...waste their time **trying** to make...,* which I assume was just a typo). If that's what you actually mean. I just thought it was an "odd" thing to say in that way, because you'd have thought if critcising others made their life boring they wouldn't do it (so it couldn't simultaneously be both the attempted remedy for boring lives AND the reason for them being boring). But the text itself is fine, sure.

Comment: OK great, now can I replace "criticizing others" with "doing so"?

Comment: Yes you can. Note that in many context you can *optionally* reverse the sequence ***doing so***. For example, *There are [some] people who waste [their] time trying to make their boring lives interesting by criticizing others, **but by/in so doing,** they actually make their lives even more boring.*